# Python3 Steganography / stepic / ValueError: Unsupported pixel format: image must be RGB, RGBA, or CMYK

Tags: python, python-3.x, steganography, stepic

I'm fairly new to python, and I'm trying out Steganography. I'm using the libraries Stepic and Image to try to encrypt user input messages onto any image. My script will do just fine until the very last step, the encryption onto the image. My error is, "ValueError: Unsupported pixel format: image must be RGB, RGBA, or CMYK" I can't think of anything to try so I've come here.
Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import stepic

i = input("Name of File (With extension): ")
img = Image.open(i)

message = input("Message: ")

message = message.encode()

encoded_img = stepic.encode(img, message)

encoded_img.save(input("Name of encypted image: "))
print("Completed!")
```

Comment: Well, what format *is* your image?  You may just need to apply `.convert('RGB')` to it at some point.

Comment: @jasonharper it is a png. I'm a little confused, where would I add convert('RGB') Much thanks, - Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the image to any supported format before you pass it to `stepic.encode()`. An example code would be:

```
from PIL import Image
import stepic

i = input("Name of File (With extension): ")
img = Image.open(i)

message = input("Message: ")

message = message.encode()

imgConv = img.convert("RGB") # Here
encoded_img = stepic.encode(imgConv, message)

encoded_img.save(input("Name of encypted image: "))
print("Completed!")
```